# Need help creating a dictionary with duplicate keys

Tags: python, pandas

I tried creating a list from dataframe columns then create a dictionary from it. However, I couldn't produce a desired output because there are multiple keys(dataframe.index, dataframe.somecolumn).

I tried:

```py
sample df: 
index sender
0      Julia
0      Alfred
0      Nana
1      Kaja
1      Lunox
1      December

dict(zip(df.index, df.sender))
```

but it only retains the first value on the sender column.

```py
desired output:
{0: [Julia, Alfred, Nana], 1: [Kaja, Lunox, December]}
```

Comment: A dict cant have duplicate keys.

Comment: I know, but how should I produce the desired output. I want to preserve the keys. I need them for mapping later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments dictionaries cannot have duplicate `keys`. One approach could be to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `index`, aggregate with the `list` constructor and use the [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method:

```
df.groupby('index').sender.apply(list).to_dict()
# {0: ['Julia', 'Alfred', 'Nana'], 1: ['Kaja', 'Lunox', 'December']}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Need to wait for 10 minutes to accept the answer haha.

Comment: Sure @SuperSaiyan Cool name :D

Comment: yea, thanks, haha. it wont allow me to accept the answer yet, need to wait 10 mins